# AngularJS - TypeError: fn is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make a function being called in a certain interval of time inside the constructor. But I don't want to write the function inside the $interval statement because it's a little big. So I wanted to make something like this:

```
this.$interval(this.getSomething(), 1000);
```

And the initialize it outside of the controller's constructor:

```
getSomething = function getSomething(){
                 ...
};
```

But it gives me an error of 
**TypeError: fn is not a function** When it seems to me as a function... Any suggestions?

Comment: According to [AngularJS $interval documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) it expects a callback.

Changing your interval part to:

    this.$interval(this.getSomething, 1000);

should work. (`()`removed)

Comment: @dquijada — Depends on if `getSomething` makes use of `this` internally or not.

Comment: Well, yes, @Quentin; but that's a more specific case. The only answer below can be checked for that case

Comment: It actually makes use of `this` internally... What's the difference? Do I have to create a var pointing to this outside and send it via argument? Going to check if the previous comments work :) Thanks for the help

Comment: @DavidCoelho — See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. Going to read it :)

Comment: And btw, @dquijada solution worked just fine. Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your function declaration to this.

```
getSomething = function(){
                 ...
};
```

and call your interval part like this.

```
this.$interval(function(){ this.getSomething() }, 1000);
```

Comment: Using an anonymous function expression instead of a named function expression will not make any difference (unless the function tries to call itself recursively, in which case it will break it).

Comment: `function(){ this.getSomething() }` won't work because the `this` context will have changed between functions.